# Dealing with an empty array when using .map() in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a React.JS component that will map the `notes` variable to display.

However, I have run into the problem of having no notes and receiving an error. What is a proper way to approach this?

Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


class List extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

render(){
  var notes = this.props.items.map((item, i)=>{
      return(
          <li className="listLink" key={i}>
              <p>{item.title}</p>
              <span>{item.content}</span>
          </li>
          )
      });
    return(
      <div className='list'>

          {notes}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

Comment: Good question I was just wondering the same thing!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you want to render the notes when at least one note exists and a default view when there are no notes in the array, you can change your render function's return expression to this:

```
return(
  <div className='list'>
      {notes.length ? notes : <p>Default Markup</p>}
  </div>
);
```

Since empty arrays in JavaScript are truthy, you need to check the array's length and not just the boolean value of an array.

Note that if your `items` prop is ever null, that would cause an exception because you'd be calling `map` on a null value.  In this case, I'd recommend using Facebook's [prop-types](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types) library to set `items` to an empty array by default.  That way, if `items` doesn't get set, the component won't break.

Comment: nice move bro !

Answer (score 16):

here is the simplest way to deal with

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';


class List extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

render(){
  var notes = this.props.items?.map((item, i)=>{
      return(
          <li className="listLink" key={i}>
              <p>{item.title}</p>
              <span>{item.content}</span>
          </li>
          )
      });
    return(
      <div className='list'>

          {notes}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

just try to add "?" for the array that you maped

Comment: Hello, can you explain why you add a question mark before the map function?

Comment: @YohanW.Dunon: this is called ["optional chaining"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) -- if "items" (in this case) is undefined or null, the optional chaining (?) will just return undefined instead of throwing an error.

Comment: this does not work for me.  Maybe because i use webpack to compile my front-end code?

Answer (score 6):

You can just setting a fallback value for the `this.props.item`

```
render() {
  const items = this.props.items || [] // if there's no items, give empty array
  const notes = items.map((item, i) => {
  return(
      ....
```

Doing `.map()` on empty array will not produces an error, but will return an empty array. Which is fine because empty array is a renderable item in react and won't produce error in `render()` and will not render the notes as there are no notes provided.

Comment: doesn't work if items is an object.  It still says the object exists so does not replace it with a list.

Answer (score 4):

In your component, you can set the ***defaultProps*** property to set the initial value to your props:

```
static defaultProps = {
    items: []
};
```