# Get data from API with Search Bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, search, axios

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      searchValue: "",
    };
  }
  updateSearch = (value) => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: value });
    if (value.trim() !== "") {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search?apiKey=1234&query=${value}&number=100`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ data: res.data });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        });
    } else {
      setState({ data: [] });
    }
}}

  render() {
    const {
      data,
      searchValue,
    } = this.state;


    return (
          <SearchBar
            placeholder="Search Food..."
            onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
            value={searchValue}
            <List style={{ paddingTop: hp("2%") }}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                {this.state.data.map(({ type }) => (
                  <Text>{this.state.type.products.title}</Text>
                ))}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </List>
```

Hi, I'm trying to get data from the Spoonacular API using a `SearchBar` and `axios` and I get the following error when I run the code: `undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.data.map...')`

Link to documentation of the Database: https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Search-Grocery-Products

Comment: Looks like you're not actually using the iteration value within your mapped data. Try swapping `this.state.type.products.title` for `type.products.title`.

Comment: thank you for answering, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying to use [map with an empty data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268267/dealing-with-an-empty-array-when-using-map-in-react).

Replace your map by a [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

```js
<FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <Text>{item.products.title}</Text>
                ))}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, the error won't show anymore, but the `Flatlist` just stays blank now, it doesn't show anything

Comment: This is normal because your state 'data' is an empty array ( [ ] ) . the flatlist will loop in his props 'data' and render component using the function given in 'renderItem'. The code given in the answer might be false because I don't know what you want to show. Try it by giving a fix value in 'data'.